# Find number of occurrences of groups of '-' sign in list in Python

Tags: python

it is my first question here.

I want to know how from this:

```
[1,1,2,'-','-',3,3,'-','-','-','-','-',5,5,'-','-','-']
```

find occurrences of `'-'` sign in this shape: `[2,5,3]`

Comment: What do you mean by in this shape?

Answer (score 5):

you can use  [`itertools groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1, 1, 2, '-', '-', 3, 3, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 5, 5, '-', '-', '-']
result = [len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(l) if k == '-']
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
[2, 5, 3]
```